# How to create inline calendar jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I'm creating an ios app using phonegap and jquerymobile.I want to create an inline calendar.like, whenever i go to a particular page i need to see the calendar displayed in that page.how to do it?thanks

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, you need to create a calendar instance on a "div" tag